# gulp-preprocess and environment variables on Windows 10

Tags: windows, gulp, gulp-preprocess

I am building a js app on OSX, and Windows 10, both running Node.js v4.2.x.

As part of my build process I run

```
BUILD_TYPE={my-build-type} gulp build
```

Which builds a particular configuration of my app, using [gulp-preprocess](https://github.com/jas/gulp-preprocess).

The relevant part of my gulp file looks like

```
var env = process.env;

...
.pipe(plug.preprocess({context: { BUILD_TYPE: env.BUILD_TYPE}}))
...
```

The relevant part of my HTML looks like

```
<!-- @if BUILD_TYPE='live' -->
    <script src="config/live.js"></script>
<!-- @endif -->

<!-- @if BUILD_TYPE='dev' -->
    <script src="config/dev.js"></script>
<!-- @endif -->

<!-- @ifndef BUILD_TYPE -->
    <script src="config/dev.js"></script>
<!-- @endif -->

<p>build type - <!-- @echo BUILD_TYPE --></p>
```

On OSX this works great, running `BUILD_TYPE=dev gulp build` results in:

```
<script src="config/dev.js"></script>

<p>build type - dev</p>
```

However, on Windows 10, using Node.js command prompt,

```
set BUILD_TYPE=dev && gulp build
```

results in:

```
<p>build type - dev</p>
```

With no script tags appearing! It's clearly recognised the environment variable, as it's printed by `@echo BUILD_TYPE`. However, none of the script elements are present.

Any clues as to why this might be happening would be much appreciated!

Oddly, if I change my gulpfile to:

```
...
.pipe(plug.preprocess({context: { BUILD_TYPE: 'dev'}}))
...
```

I get the expected output:

```
<script src="config/dev.js"></script>

<p>build type - dev</p>
```

Further still, if I log the variable before invoking `preprocess`:

**OSX**

```
console.log(env.BUILD_TYPE);
//dev
console.log(typeof env.BUILD_TYPE);
//string
console.log(env.BUILD_TYPE === 'dev');
//true
```

**Windows 10**

```
console.log(env.BUILD_TYPE);
//dev
console.log(typeof env.BUILD_TYPE);
//string
console.log(env.BUILD_TYPE === 'dev');
//false!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you ensured you are setting the environment variable using no spaces after defining it.

Something like:

`set BUILD_TYPE=dev&&gulp build`